# is there any normal form value post options in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

i need to send some parameters from js to php server side . it should go like ordinary form submit. should not create hidden form and post the data. and should not send as ajax request.

is there any solution for this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "go like ordinary form submit", but "not send as ajax request."? Do you mean you want the user to be redirected when it sends? location.href = "/" to redirect users in js

Comment: yes correct .. need redirect and also have to submit post values.